# Need a quicker way to search multiple compressed files

Tags: bash

I have 18 dir:

- /logs/server1
- /logs/server2
- /logs/server3
- /logs/server4
- and 14 more, but it's only the server1 - 4 i want to look in.

In each dir there are 6 logfiles:

- file-2021-06-01.tar.gz
- file-2021-06-02.tar.gz
- file-2021-06-03.tar.gz
- file-2021-06-04.tar.gz
- file-2021-06-05.tar.gz
- file-2021-06-06.tar.gz

The files look like:
***2021-06-01 09:49:58.707 MO [UDP 10.100.110.120:4096] (372C102D55F......***
The compressed files are ~7GB each

And, i have a list with 1000 ip-addresses:

- /script/ip.lst

I have a script-dir:

- /script

What is the fastest way to grep just the first occurence of the IP, in any of the files.
My problem is that if the IP only exist in the last file ( server4/file-2021-06-06.tar.gz ) it take ~1 hour to find it.

My script looks like this right now:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGS="/logs"
IPS="/script/ip.lst"
DIRS="/script/logdirs.lst" # A list with 4 log-dir i want to search in 

while read ip; do
    FOUND="0"
        LOG="/home/wcar_op/encryption_error/$ip-MO.log"
        while read dirs; do
                zcat $LOGS/file.2021-06-0*.gz | ./ack-v3.5.0 -1 " MO \[UDP $ip" | tee >> $LOG
        [ "${PIPESTATUS[1]}" -eq "0" ] && break && echo "Found" && FOUND="1"
        done < $DIRS
        echo "FOUND: $FOUND"
        [ "${FOUND}" -eq "1" ] && continue
done < $IPS
```

Can it ( of course it can ) be done faster in some way ??
If the IP is found in the first file i want the script to skip to the next IP.

Comment: Do you only want to know in what file the IP is? Or do you want a line number>

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I need the complete line with that ip.

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) instead of `ack` 2) Use something like `rg -az -m1 -f ip.lst file.tar.gz` instead of using `while` loop. You can use `sed 's/^/ MO [UDP /' ip.lst` to add the prefix

Comment: @Claes : Please remove the _grep_  tag, since you seem to intend using `ack` instead.

Comment: Removed the tag, i was not allowed to use ack as tag.

Comment: Sundeep, i'll try your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: Another possibility would be to grep files in parallel; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898949

Comment: I would suggest instead of decompressing each log file again and again in the inner loop, you decompress one file, and search all the `ips` in it ( make this one inner loop ) and keep an array to keep track of found ip's and if all ip's are found, you can just break out of the loop and not decompress more files. I am not really a bash person so idk how this can be done but just a hint which maybe might help you.

Comment: @Claes forgot to mention `-F` option for the `rg` command since you do not seem to need regex here (the `sed` command also puts `[` character literally instead of escaped form)

Comment: To deCompress the files has no effect at all, it was actually quicker with zgrep.
zgrep IP file.gz was 3 minute 5 sec
gzip -d file.gz was 3 min 40 sec and then i need to do the grep as well.

I decide to do this in 2 steps:
First thing will be to find all occurence of the IP's:

while read file
    zgrep -E 'ALL_1028_IP' $file
< $LIST_OF_FILES

And then continuing from there.
That would limit the next step a bit.
Each file is ~25.000.000 lines and with the above i can limit this to ~1.000.000

Comment: >  My problem is that if the IP only exist in the last file ( server4/file-2021-06-06.tar.gz ) it take ~1 hour to find it.
how much time does it take now with the optimizations? ( also, after all the optimisations, you can post a solution yourself and mark it as accepted )