# Grep surnames from multiple files to multiple subdirectories

Tags: macos, awk, terminal, grep

I'm trying to pull the lines from text files scattered in tens of thousands of subdirectories which contain [surname] from 15 text files of ~100 lines each in the format:

[firstname] [surname]

or

[firstname] [middlename] [surname]

So carry out the ~1500 searches into all subdirectories and compile all of the lines into one single file surnames.txt

Thank you.

Comment: [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. It's not enough to state the format of one of the input files, we need to see truly representative examples of the input files so we can best understand the problem and test a potential solution with,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all files in the directory (and subdirectories) are only the .txt files you want to search, then the following should suffice.

```sh
grep surname -rh . > surnames.txt
```

where the flags mean:

- `-r` recursively searches subdirectories.
- `-h` prevents the filename from being printed out.

If not all files are .txt files, you should narrow your search to only .txt files using find:

```sh
find . -name \*.txt -exec grep surname -h {} + > surnames.txt
```

If this is something you're gonna do often, you should look into doing this search in parallel, something akin to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899028/13040392).

Comment: Given a surname of `John` to search for that would find `Bob Johnston`, `John Smith`, etc.

Comment: @Ed Morton, I see what you mean. It was unclear from the question _exactly_ what OP wants. If OP clarifies, I'll update my answer.